# How to bind html to ngModel in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an input control like TextArea where I use `[(ngModel)]` for two way 
    binding. When displaying data that is HTML, it displays with HTML tags instead of interpreting it. For instance, I have HTML string `<b>text</b>` I want it to 
 be displayed as **text**. How can I do that with ngModel?

Comment: Text like this inside the textarea? Native textarea tag don't really support Richtext I guess. You'll have to use a third-party textarea component that supports such an input.

Answer (score 0):

Have made a stackblitz for this, please check this out:

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngmodel-ngmodel-for-html-output

Well this is what I am doing here:

> This is the HTML where for the text area I am using ngModel to see checkout the HTML and returning the HTML result in the below div.

```
<textarea 
  [(ngModel)]="content"
  cols="50" 
  rows="10"></textarea>

<br><br><br>

<div [innerHtml]="content"></div>
```

> This is the TypeScript File where I am initially giving an Input but it's not important. Make sure to atleast define the property.

```
content = 
`<h2>Hello</h2>
<p>This is a great example...</p>
`;
```

I hope this solves your issue...

Comment: Let me know if this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you. What I need is to also display the html in text area not in a div. Basically, user can enter text in a text area, click save and it saves to the database. Then the saved text is displayed in the same text area so the user can update it. So what I need is to use [innerHtml] to display the html text correctly, then also be able to bind text back to database to be able to update.

Comment: Is there a way to get angular to process directives in the HTML?  i.e. if you add a component to the project and then reference that component in the HTML in the text area <app-new-component></app-new-component> ?

Comment: @jim i didn't understand your question. Are you asking if we can create a component and refer to it in textbox to use it?